# Catch Unhandled exception in mvc4

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

How can i catch unhandeld exception in mvc4, [without using ELMAH].
I tried Invoking `Application_Error` ,  it works but logs all error including script not found and path of image not found which is not needed.

Example of error which can be excluded

> The controller for path '/Image/*.png' was not found or does not implement IController
>
> The controller for path '/~/Scripts/*.js' was not found or does not implement IController

Code

```
void Application_Error(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{
   Exception exc = Server.GetLastError();
   //logging Exception (exc)
 }
```

Comment: @ Patrick Hofman I have added the code above.do u need further

Comment: What are you having trouble with? Excluding some types of exceptions? What types?

Comment: execptions like script not found on path or image not found like that.

Comment: And what is the type of those exceptions?

Comment: exception of type : HttpException And httpEx.GetHttpCode() = 404

Answer (score 0):

Create a custom error handler and catch what you want (and log it) and ignore what you don't want.

### CustomHandleErrorAttribute

```
public class CustomHandleErrorAttribute : HandleErrorAttribute
{
    public override void OnException(ExceptionContext filterContext)
    {
        if (!(filterContext.Exception is InvalidOperationException))
        {
            // log
        }
    }
}
```

### FilterConfig

You will need to globally register the error handler.

```
public class FilterConfig
{
    public static void RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilterCollection filters)
    {
        filters.Add(new HandleErrorAttribute());
        filters.Add(new CustomHandleErrorAttribute());
    }
}
```

Comment: You don't need to create a CustomHandleErrorAttribute you can just use HandleErrorAtteribute and specify the ExceptionType property which will contain typefo(InvalidOperationException).

Comment: @Rowan Freeman CustomHandleErrorAttribute not if the controller name is incorrect

Comment: @CodeNotFound It depends if you want to specify which exceptions you catch or which ones you don't. In this case I'm filtering out ones I don't want.

Comment: @PintuPaul You'd have to configure it how you like it. This is just a sample that will need filling in.

Answer (score 0):

these Errors are unhandled exception.i think you can get this error type and ignore it for logging

```
  protected void Application_Error()
    {

        var ex = Server.GetLastError();

        if(check exceptiontype)
        {}

}
```

Comment: I have done that, i think it will catch only invalid action exception